# How to generate lint, complexity, code coverage, cyclometrics report from Angular app?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-test

My client is looking for the lint, complexity, code coverage, cyclometrics reports. I know that we can create code coverage from testing, but how about the rest of them?

I don't have any idea how to generate them for an Angular application.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good explanation [here](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/taking-code-coverage-to-newer-heights-with-ease-angular-karma-vs-code-3a8ba81d4d8c) written by **Shashank Vivek**. On creating lint please find the link [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/bending-tslint-to-your-needs-6ae0a51e633) written by 
**Tim Deschryver**

Comment: This is not a useful answer, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer